# .js.erb is evil. Is there a better way to put keys in JS?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have an API key (Stripe) that has be in the JS file

I currently have it in a .js.erb file like this:

```
SomeAPI.setPubKey('<%= ENV["SOME_API_PUBLIC_KEY"] %>');
```

My client likes to switch keys a lot (new live keys, switch to test, then back to live, etc.)

For heroku to update the key I have to "save" the "new" file (technically it hasn't changed). Push to git, push to heroku, to trigger a recompile.

Is there a different or better way to access keys in JS files?

Comment: No, since they're coming from Ruby. What you *can* do is create a file of JS "constants" and isolate it to a *single* file, and you then reference that set of constants from all your other JS. For example, I use that to expose a subset of Rails routes so I have path helper values in my JS.

Comment: (Not quite true, you could expose things like this via an Ajax call as well, which I've also done, but for keys it seems a bit expensive. YMMV.)

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah, I thought of that. Seemed a bit much to me too

Comment: You can set them as constants in your page's DOM.